# Magento get products by website id and store id

Tags: products, product-list, stores, websites

I am working in magento one website multiple stores platform, i successfully created one website with 3 stores and 3 store view. I assigned a category to my default store and products in it, but i getting other products also. Let me know how i can go to correct direction.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addWebsiteFilter($website_id)->addAttributeToFilter‌​('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
$collection->getSelect()->limit(8);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$websiteIds = array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
$collection->addWebsiteFilter($websiteIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your category has the flag "Is anchor" set to `Yes` then it will display products from its subcategories too.
Also, rebuilding your indexes won't hurt either.

Comment: My requirement is display products on front page, i am not displaying categories here.

Comment: Then you should post the code you are using.

Comment: $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)
                          ->getCollection()
                          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addWebsiteFilter($website_id)->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
      $collection->getSelect()->limit(8); This is my query by which i am getting products.